# How to interface to a HyperRAM with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, sram

A couple of manufacturers have had this low pin count **HyperBus** interface now for a few years. It seems like finally there might be a way to get a few megabytes of RAM into a microcontroller project.

Has anybody had any success with interfacing to one of these SRAM chips with any common microcontroller?

For your reference, here's a datasheet of one 8 megabyte SRAM that uses this bus:
http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/66-67WVH8M8ALL-BLL.pdf
[image]

Comment: This is just a guess, but without a dedicated hardware interface from the controller to the SRAM, performance would probably be too low to be useful and memory management would be cumbersome.

Comment: I'm doubtful it could work. The datasheet notes that CS# cannot be pulled down for more than Tcsa time to prevent blocking internal refreshes. If you've got a micro twiddling GPIO pins to drive the RAM, there's no way you can do it fast enough tomavoid violating this spec.

Answer (score 3):

This HyperBus can only be found on a few Spansion/Cypress microcontrollers, it seems (the Traveo range, with Cortex R5F). So unless you planned to use MCUs from this specific family, you'll have to bit-bang the HyperBus interface using GPIOs.

Bit-banging would be a big performance hit for the CPU. It seems you have to toggle the CK/CK# lines 17 times for a single read cycle (and you, of course, also have the D0-D7 and other control lines to set appropriately all along this cycle). Now, let's say you have a 20MHz CPU and you need, on average, four CPU cycles per CK/CK# toggling (*very* optimistic, since you also have to manage the other bus lines within this budget), it means you need at least 50ns*17*4 = 3.4µS to achieve a read cycle.

Ax DoxyLover mentioned, there is a maximum Chip Select low time (certainly to allow the chip to manage the refresh timings internally) that is specified at 4.0µS. Our optimistic estimation is too close to this to be realistic. So, in addition to be a performance hit, it will most likely fail to work.

What makes much more sense, if you need that much RAM, is choosing a MCU that has a dedicated SDRAM interface. There are lots of Cortex-M that have it, now (LPC18xx/43xx, STM32F427/429/469, STM32F7, ...). The bus requires routing more signals, but it will give you much more flexibility in the choice of components, will be cheaper, and will run much faster.

Comment: Interesting note about the maximum CS time. Hmm... Let's say that I have a bus controller that can clock in and out bursts of 8-bit data using RD# and WR# signals. Do you see any possibilities in using simple external logic to create the CK/CK# signals from RD# and WR# ?

Comment: The problem isn't just the generation of CK/CK#. There is also the RWDS signal (which is bidirectional, by the way). And the DQn signals also are bidirectional, and they convey both the address and data. Really, I don't think it can be made just with a few gates. I wouldn't try. What's wrong with SDRAM?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights! Hmm.. I'm not sure that I can use SDRAM; you see, I'm actually trying to stretch the capabilities of a system that's already deployed by making a RAM add-on card. I was thinking that if someone has been able to adapt a generic MCU to use HyperRAM, I could perhaps figure out how to do it... but it does seem difficult. I could use a CPLD, perhaps, but it is cost critical so I don't know, really. Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, a CPLD would certainly allow you to make what you want... *But*... If your project is cost critical, and you must use a CPLD anyway, with a bit more work, you can certainly make the same CPLD (or maybe the one with just a bit more I/Os) interface a standard SDRAM (which is a fourth the price of HyperRAM)... Well, right, I can be a bit stubborn sometimes. But honestly, I think it is worth considering the option, even though I'm certainly not aware of all the constraints that are relevant in this design choice.

Comment: Thanks again for another good idea, I must think about it. One last question, if you don't mind. I've been a bit afraid of SDRAMs, having the feeling that they have a high pin count and are notoriously difficult to interface to. Could you give a few bits of very basic info and steer me towards some info to study? how many pins are needed to interface to a standrard SDRAM? Do I need to generate refreshing logic? And for further information do you have any pointers to datasheets of one or more device that represents this class of devices?  Sorry for troubling you one last time!

Comment: No problem. Yes, they have higher pin count (typically 8 control lines, 14 address lines and 16 data lines for a 8Mbytes chip). But since, on the CPLD design, you can choose where you place your I/O pins, you can still make a design that will be easy to route (maybe even on a two layer board). And yes, you'll have to manage the refresh timings yourself. There is an auto refresh mechanism in the SDRAM to make things easier, but it is still your responsibility to trigger it...

Comment: There are some SDRAM controller HDL designs available at opencores.org. Maybe you can get a few ideas there. And here is a datasheet from [ISSI](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/198/42-45S16400J-258565.pdf), which is a typical single data rate SDRAM of 8Mbytes. Granted, it isn't the most trivial task, but it is workable.

Comment: @PkP Last idea to simplify things: try to delegate most of the burden on the software side. For example, if the timings allow it on the MCU, issue a special command every 64ms to the CPLD, that will trigger the 4096 refresh cycles in one shot, rather than handling this triggering from the CPLD itself. This way, you'll avoid contentions, and this will simplify the HDL a lot. You could even delegate the handling of the ACTIVATE and PRECHARGE commands to the software. Good luck.